# thunderbird syncs all folders

Tags: thunderbird, evolution, email, imap

Why does Thunderbird sync all folders?  While I prefer Thunderbird to Evolution, the out of the box setting is inverted for me -- Evolution never did that.  In Thunderbird, I had to manually unclick many, many, many folders.  In particular, the [gmail] folders, which hold the "all mail" directory, and so forth.

Comment: Evolution is not Thunderbird. All programs do not act the same way

Comment: Correct, BlueXrider, all programs do not act the same way.  Out of the box, for me, Thunderbird acts in a way which sucks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's the Migration Assistant in the help menu which can set all of your folders to not synchronize.  I think this was turned on to improve performance in general.

Comment: Ok, I'll check that out, thanks.  I just find it curious that the setting was, out of the box, to sync all folder.